# Trouble in alignment of matrix in subquestions

Tags: matrices

Please let me know how to fix the problem of alignment of matrix equation in the sub question. In question 4 (b) the matrix gets its position in the center whereas I want it just from the beginning. Same thing in the starting part of question 4 where I declared the general form of the matrix, it takes two lines? I am putting down the latex itself so that someone can  correct it there itself. Thanks

```
\documentclass[11pt,paper=a4,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx,lastpage}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{censor}
\censorruledepth=-.2ex
\censorruleheight=.1ex
\hyphenpenalty 10000
\usepackage[paperheight=10.5in,paperwidth=8.27in,bindingoffset=0in,left=0.8in,right=1in,
top=0.7in,bottom=1in,headsep=.5\baselineskip]{geometry}
\flushbottom
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\renewcommand\ULthickness{2pt}   %%---> For changing thickness of underline
\setlength\ULdepth{1.5ex}%\maxdimen ---> For changing depth of underline
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\pagestyle{empty}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\headrule
\newcommand{\continuedmessage}{%
\ifcontinuation{\footnotesize Question \ContinuedQuestion\ continues\ldots}{}%
 }
\runningheader{\footnotesize Mathematics}
{\footnotesize Mathematics --- Differential Geometry}
{\footnotesize Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
\footrule
\footer{\footnotesize Student's name:}
{}
{\ifincomplete{\footnotesize Question \IncompleteQuestion\ continues
on the next page\ldots}{\iflastpage{\footnotesize End of exam}{\footnotesize Please go        on to the next page\ldots}}}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}
\crefname{question}{question}{questions}
%==============================================================


\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\pointsinrightmargin
\pointsdroppedatright
\marksnotpoints
\pointpoints{mark}{marks}
\pointformat{\boldmath\themarginpoints}
\bracketedpoints
\question
Why is there air?

\question
What if there were no air?

\begin{parts}
\part
Describe the effect on the balloon industry.

\part
Describe the effect on the aircraft industry.
\end{parts}

\question
\begin{parts}
\part
Define the universe.  Give three examples.

\part
If the universe were to end, how would you know?
\end{parts}
\question
If $S \in Mat_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ is of the form 
\begin{displaymath} 
\left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\
c & d  \\
\end{array} \right) \end{displaymath},
 then prove the following:
\begin{parts}
\part[3] $S$ is a subring of $ Mat_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$. \droppoints
\part[2] \begin{equation}\nonumber
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b  \\ c & 0
\end{pmatrix}^{k}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a^{k} & x \\ 0 & c^{k}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\part[3] \begin{displaymath} 
\left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\
c & d  \\
\end{array} \right) \end{displaymath}
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use display math if you don't want equations centered:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,paper=a4,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx,lastpage}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{censor}
\censorruledepth=-.2ex
\censorruleheight=.1ex
\hyphenpenalty 10000
\usepackage[paperheight=10.5in,paperwidth=8.27in,bindingoffset=0in,left=0.8in,right=1in,
top=0.7in,bottom=1in,headsep=.5\baselineskip]{geometry}
\flushbottom
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\renewcommand\ULthickness{2pt}   %%---> For changing thickness of underline
\setlength\ULdepth{1.5ex}%\maxdimen ---> For changing depth of underline
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\pagestyle{empty}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\headrule
\newcommand{\continuedmessage}{%
\ifcontinuation{\footnotesize Question \ContinuedQuestion\ continues\ldots}{}%
 }
\runningheader{\footnotesize Mathematics}
{\footnotesize Mathematics --- Differential Geometry}
{\footnotesize Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
\footrule
\footer{\footnotesize Student's name:}
{}
{\ifincomplete{\footnotesize Question \IncompleteQuestion\ continues
on the next page\ldots}{\iflastpage{\footnotesize End of exam}{\footnotesize Please go        on to the next page\ldots}}}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}
\crefname{question}{question}{questions}
%==============================================================


\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\pointsinrightmargin
\pointsdroppedatright
\marksnotpoints
\pointpoints{mark}{marks}
\pointformat{\boldmath\themarginpoints}
\bracketedpoints
\question
Why is there air?

\question
What if there were no air?

\begin{parts}
\part
Describe the effect on the balloon industry.

\part
Describe the effect on the aircraft industry.
\end{parts}

\question
\begin{parts}
\part
Define the universe.  Give three examples.

\part
If the universe were to end, how would you know?
\end{parts}
\question
If $S \in Mat_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ is of the form 
$ 
\left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\
c & d  \\
\end{array} \right) $,
 then prove the following:
\begin{parts}
\part[3] $S$ is a subring of $ Mat_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$. \droppoints
\part[2] $
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b  \\ c & 0
\end{pmatrix}^{k}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a^{k} & x \\ 0 & c^{k}
\end{pmatrix}
$
\part[3] $ 
\left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\
c & d  \\
\end{array} \right) $
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ricci1729: If the solution worked for you please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) and perhaps [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).